# Determine Data Type

Tags: grails, groovy

I have this code in my controller:

```
def cols = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.archie.Build').persistentProperties.collect {it.name}
```

The code above will allow me to list all the property names I have in Build class. Now, I would like to include also the properties data type, ie. boolean, String etc...

Somewhat like the output is:

```
[floorType:String, floorWidth:Float, ......]
```

Maybe not exactly like that, or maybe similar, but as long as I can return their data type. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entry in `persistentProperties` is a [GrailsDomainClassProperty](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClassProperty.html), and this provides access to the type of the property as a `Class` object:

```
def props = [:]
grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.archie.Build'
    ).persistentProperties.each {
      props[it.name] = it.type.name
    }
```

Or just pass the `persistentProperties` array itself through to the GSP, then extract `.name` and `.type` there.

You may also wish to consider using `constrainedProperties` instead of/in addition to the `persistentProperties`. The `constrainedProperties` map lists only those properties that are mentioned in the domain class constraints block, but the iterator over this map is guaranteed to return the properties in the order they are listed in the constraints. This is how the default scaffolding operates, as I'm not aware of any way to control the order of the `persistentProperties` array.